# Computing the Spectral Measure of a stationary sequence : Am I doing this right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am trying to compute the spectral measure of a stationary sequence and would like to know whether my thoughts are correct. I can use the result for a more involved question, thus just seeking confirmation for now :-)

The setup is :

$\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $I : L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the identity operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $I : f \rightarrow f$. I choose an arbitrary $s \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and define the sequence $\mathbf{s} = \{s_n = I^ns\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$. I want to determine the spectral measure $\mu_s$ of $\mathbf{s}$ which is defined via the auto-correlation

$R_s(n) = \langle s_n, s_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \cdot \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} e^{- i n \theta} d \mu_s(\theta)$ with $d\mu_s(\theta) = \Phi_s(\theta) d \theta + d\mu_s^{singular}(\theta)$

**My thoughts :**

1. Since the identity operator is unitary, the sequence $\mathbf{s}$ is indeed. stationary to begin with.
2. The spectral measure can be further broken down into the absolutely integrable part and the singular part via : $R_s(n) = \langle s_n, s_0 \rangle = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [\Phi_s(\theta) + \sum_{k} c_k \delta(\theta - \theta_k)] d \theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \cdot \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \Phi_s(\theta) e^{-i n \theta} d \theta + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_k c_k e^{-i n \theta_k}$
3. For the identity operator, we obviously have that $s_n(t) = (I^n s_0)(t) = (I^n s)(t) = s(t)$ for all $n$.
4. This gives the auto-correlation to be $R_s(n) = \langle s_n, s_0 \rangle = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} s(t) \overline{s(t)} dt = \left\| s \right\|^2$
5. The $\Phi_s$ of the absolutely integrable part must be 0 because if it is not, $R_s(n)$ would contain a component (which is this absolutely integrable part) that converges to 0 for $n \rightarrow \infty$. The absolutely integrable part is thus the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of $\Phi_s$.
6. With this, the autocorrelation becomes simply $R_s(n) = \left\| s \right\|^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_k c_k e^{- i n \theta_k}$. It remains to find out the parameters $c_k$ and $\theta_k$.
7. I would argue that this expression is "1-periodic". Am I thus correct in assuming $\theta_k = 0$ for all $k$ ? And if so, how to obtain $c_k$?

**The result should then look like this :** $\mu_s(d\theta) = \sum_k c_k \delta(\theta - \theta_k) d \theta$

I would appreciate somebody **giving me the last tipp**. I need this proof to show something different in my thesis. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you check your definition of spectral measure?  How come you have an integral with two "$d\theta$"?

Comment: Hi @Ruy, thanks, I completely messed up here. I fixed the typos, these should now all be correct definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I think you are asking for the measure $\mu_s$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ whose Fourier coefficients are given by $\hat\mu_s(n)=\|s\|^2$, right? In that case, the answer is simply $$
\mu_s=2\pi\|s^2\|\delta_0,$$
where $\delta_0$ is Dirac's measure supported on $\{0\}$.  Thus the absolutely continuous part vanishes since $\mu_s$ is singular.

Comment: thank you very much! This is now clear to me, I shoul've thought about the Fourier transformation rules. However, it now bugs me to understand how to get the $c_k$ and $\theta_k$ values. Or let's say, not specifically Fourier related, how to dissolve the sum and obtain the parameters "per hand".

Comment: I don't understand your definition of the coefficients $c_k$ nor the $\theta_k$ in (2).  Is the term inside square brackets a function?  If so the integral of $\delta(\theta-\theta_k)$ against Lebesgue measure $d\theta$ vanishes.

Comment: Yes exactly, it is a function and when integrating, we obtain the subsequent expression in 2. This is as defined in my script to functional analysis. Sadly, no more comments are given on that there .... I suppose that this is just a sum of values corresponding to "singular" values in case the absolutely integrable part vanishes as in this case which means that the few (or periodic) values of the $R_s(n)$ can be  expressed by a sum of singular values. Else the information would be lost.

Comment: I am sorry but the "subsequent expression" is incorrect.  Some people like to abuse of the notation $d\theta$, which is ok asl long as you know what you're doing.  But there is a risk that it leads you to plain wrong statements as this one.  Without a proper definition of the coefficients I'm afraid I can help no further.

Comment: thank you very much until now! I will pass the comment on to my professor, you are absolutely right and I am also a bit confused. Anyways, thanks again!!!